# Amazon S3 and Cloud Drive signed URLs?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-clouddrive

i have reed the link https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive but there isn't nothing for PHP to signed URL like this form:

```
$authentication_params = "AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWS_S3_KEY;
$authentication_params.= "&Expires={$expires}";
$authentication_params.= "&Signature={$signature}";

return $link = "http://s3.amazonAWS.com/{$bucket}/{$resource}?{$authentication_params}";
```

so i want to know if i can get the files in my Cloud Drive Amazon folder with this method, or maybe, a file URL sharing... Thanks

PD: i want to know if exist encryption for bucket or folders?

Comment: Do you want to use Amazon CloudDrive, or Amazon S3?

Comment: Amazon CloudDrive! But... por example, i want an URL like this:
https://zcd-00.s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/
A1U8PWYOT4FQ20/rENkkEuQFEptXSmU6BihLahNJyQkPbOtrQrUhfWhf
/tlhFAj7pb9ZI2RHkiIJF/a%2Bug1LBcqTtXdls/
6EcgwwQRZcmUGA9NNyCiitAOYUNVVbwI5MXCjrzNmHqFjeO4ZGz%2B%2B8mLtSJq%2BcqfEqUWdN4bDSATrGQvgUQD4r8D2W0x1EGMbXbPxVnu46rJJ5GpayJ0R8Yz9pwFkpmT6i0
/g8o1ACgmGcwprh%2BH16wmKJNhK5itgq7lykP9cHkiTkjv0iPqQekkuE4BS%2BGgdbRn2uEkZmlVcc%2Brdw06naIhdlOn?
Expires=$expires
&response-expires=$date
&response-content-disposition=attachment$file
&AWSAccessKeyId=$key
&x-amz-security-token=$token
&Signature=$signature

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888733/url-is-amazon-s3-or-s3-with-clouddrive

Answer (score 1):

Amazon CloudDrive is a totally separate service to Amazon S3.

CloudDrive is provided by Amazon, whereas S3 is provided by Amazon Web Services. Different products made by different teams for different purposes.